# compare a dynamic text box with another column in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a dynamic Textbox in a gridview. Here on textchange I want to compare the value with another column in the same grid. my code is given below.

Here my doubt is that, How can I get the 2nd value to compare in TextChanged.

```
             if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.ID = "txt";
            txt.Text = e.Row.Cells[7].Text;
            txt.AutoPostBack = true;
            txt.TextChanged += new EventHandler(Txt_TextChanged);
            e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(txt);
        }

   private void Txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text) && txtBox.Text.All(Char.IsDigit))
        { 

//Here I want to get the gridview's 6th column(gridview.row[i].cells[6].text)
        }
        else
        {

        }
        }
```

--
thanks

Comment: why dont you use `CellValueChanged `instead? what is the difference?

Comment: @Badiparmagi , how does that work. sample please.

Answer (score 1):

I would use .Equals() or object.Equals(editedCell, otherCell) if one of the Cells could be null.

```
private void Txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
        TextBox txtBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text) && txtBox.Text.All(Char.IsDigit))
        {
            if(object.Equals(gridview.row[i].cells[6].text, txtBox.Text))
            {
                //Equal
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to tell you, I am not able to find CellValueChanged event in my grid. can you please guide me.

Comment: mine is Gridview , not DatagridView

Answer (score 0):

if you know cell index, its much easier. here i compared the cell that edited and cell[1] in the row. check this:

```
 private void myDataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
         {
                var editedCell = 
myDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
                var otherCell =
 myDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                if (editedCell == otherCell)
                {
                    //equal
                }

               else
                   //not equal

         }
```

Comment: ,Sorry to tell you, I am not able to find CellValueChanged event in my grid. can you please guide me.

Comment: mine is Gridview , not DatagridView

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend not adding TextBoxes dynamically in the `OnRowDataBound` event, but using a `TemplateField` instead. The reason is that the TextBoxes will disappear after PostBack and to get them back you will need to call `DataBind()` again.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox CssClass='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("value") %>' OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And now we can handle the `OnTextChanged` event in code behind. The problem is getting the correct row number. For this I "abused" the `CssClass` property of the TextBox (`CssClass='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'`). By setting the row number as a class you can easily access it in code behind

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;

    int rowNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.CssClass);
    string valueToCompare = GridView1.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[1].Text;

    if (textBox.Text == valueToCompare)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```